# How do you let a PDFView know that a PDF has been changed in memory so it can update?

Tags: macos, cocoa, pdfview

I have two PDFViews that sit side by side, both displaying the same PDF. If the user adds an annotation to one pdf, I'd like it the second view to update. I have the following code, but weirdly, if the user selects something in the `firstPDF` view, clicks the highlight button, the `secondPDF` is the one that displays the highlight annotations. Does anyone know why this is? Or how to change the behavior so both PDFs update? I've tried the following in the `highlightPDF` function, but none of those seem to help.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstPDF: PDFView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondPDF: PDFView!

    @IBAction func selectPDF(_ sender: Any) {
        // gets PDF URL, creates PDF
        if let url = askForFile(),
            let pdf = PDFDocument(url: url) {
            firstPDF.document = pdf
            secondPDF.document = pdf

        }
    }
    @IBAction func highlightPDF(_ sender: Any) {
        firstPDF.highlight()


        // things i have tried to make the firstPDF reload the pdf from memory
        firstPDF.needsDisplay = true
        firstPDF.displayIfNeeded()
        firstPDF.layoutDocumentView()
        firstPDF.layout()
        if let page = firstPDF.currentPage {
            firstPDF.annotationsChanged(on: page)
        }
    }


}

extension PDFView {
        func highlight() {
            guard let selections = self.currentSelection?.selectionsByLine() else { return }
            selections.forEach { selection in
                selection.pages.forEach { page in
                    let highlight = PDFAnnotation(bounds: selection.bounds(for: page), forType: .highlight, withProperties: nil)
                    highlight.endLineStyle = .circle
                    highlight.color = NSColor.yellow.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
                    page.addAnnotation(highlight)



                }
            }

        }


}
```

If I change the order of the select pdf assignment like so:

```
secondPDF.document = pdf
firstPDF.document = pdf
```

The opposite happens. `firstPDF` displays the annotation, but `secondPDF` does not.

Comment: Apparently `PDFDocument` and `PDFPage` don't support two views.

Comment: @Willeke this seems bad. I've found a workaround by subclassing PDFView and creating a refreshDoc function that is ```if let pdf = self.document, let dest = self.currentDestination {
            self.document = nil;
            self.document = pdf;
            self.go(to: dest);
        }``` This is a very inelegant way of doing things.